# Helping someone cheat

Tags: phrases, vocabulary

When someone, for example, uses a note on an exam to answer the questions, we say they **cheat** on the exam. What if someone else helps them to answer the questions, for example passing a note to them, or whispering the answer to them? Is there a VERB or VERB PHRASE meaning *helping someone with cheating* on an exam?

Comment: *To partake in cheating*, perhaps.

Comment: A "cheat partner" may refer to the helper.

Comment: @Graffito  what about a verb or phrase for the act?!

Comment: Perhaps **Collusion**: Collusion is an agreement between two or more parties, sometimes illegal and therefore secretive, to limit open competition by deceiving, misleading, or defrauding others of their legal rights, or to obtain an objective forbidden by law typically by defrauding or gaining an unfair market advantage. It is an agreement among firms or individuals to divide a market, set prices, limit production or limit opportunities. (*source Wikipedia*)

Comment: I don't see any problem in using "accomplice". Helping someone to cheat is also cheating.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with "accomplice".

Comment: +1 for 'Accomplice'. They are guilty of 'collusion', and they may also be an **accessory to the crime.** ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessory_%28legal_term%29))

Comment: @Graffito Please post answers as answers, not comments. Please also set mentions in italic not bold.

Comment: @Rathony accomplice is a noun referring to the person. Can you think of a verb or verb phrase referring to the act?

Comment: @Cheiloproclitic How common is cheating in our lives? Not very common. I don't think English has a specific verb to mean helping someone to cheat on the exam. As mentioned above, it's just another form of cheating. You can say, "He cheated on the exam by helping someone with a note."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe conspiring to cheat?  Aiding and abetting?  Assisting?  Facilitating?  Acting as an accessory?

Comment: When offering word suggestions it's generally expected that you provide quoted definitions for those words demonstrating why those words are applicable.

Comment: @Jim It is also necessary to present an argument in one’s own words why the answered believes that the word or words presented are actually what’s being looked for. Just quoting a dictionary is not a very good answer, and may not be an answer at all.

Comment: @tchrist- most assuredly.